# Pandas qcut with groupby with non-unique values

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to do a groupby on a pandas dataframe and on that groupby do a qcut, to classify the values on a quantile. The problem is that some groups have only one value, so qcut complains with `ValueError: Bin edges must be unique`. Is there a way to simply ignore these cases on the groupby and qcut?

I'm doing something like

```
df['quantile'] = df.groupby(['grouping'])['values'].transform(
                 lambda x: pd.qcut(x, 4))
```

I can do this way on a two level grouping

```
pd.qcut(df.groupby(['grouping', 'param1']).sum()['value'],[0.15,0.25,0.5,0.75,1.0], labels=['0.15', '0.25', '0.5', '0.75'])
```

But I'm not sure that the results are the quantiles inside each group for the parameter `grouping` or for the entire dataframe.

Comment: You could pass the result of pandas' `quantile` method to numpy's `digitize` function.  It won't throw an error; in those cases it will assign the integer associated with the last quantile.

Comment: My [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37434328/5276797) could help...

Answer (score 0):

within qcut method, you could set duplicates='drop'.  This should produce a small number of null values for the qcut transformation that you could decide to impute to whatever value you wish.